# Как читать коллекции из колонки главной таблицы в переменную с типом коллекции программного блока?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, коллекции

Не могу разобраться до конца с принципом работы вложенных таблиц.

Такой вопрос, вот есть конструкция:

```
DECLARE <Объект-коллекция>  <Тип ВТ>;
<Переменная-элемент коллекции >  <Тип из БД>;
J integer := 0;
BEGIN . . . . . . END;
```

Подскажите, что должно располагаться между `BEGIN` и `END`?

Со всем, что располагается выше в конструкции, в целом разобралась.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> что должно располагаться между `BEGIN` и `END`?

Там реализуется логика, в данном случае - чтение коллекции из колонки таблицы:

```
create or replace type nttype is table of varchar2 (8)
/
create table main_table (val) as
    select 'val '||rownum from dual connect by level<=9
/
declare
    object_collection nttype := nttype ('a','b','c');
    element_of_collection varchar2 (8);
    j int := 7;
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line ('collection has '||object_collection.count||' elements'); 
    select val bulk collect into object_collection
    from main_table;
    dbms_output.put_line (
        'collection has '||object_collection.count||
        ' elements, element of collection ('||j||') is "'||object_collection(j)||'"'); 
end;
/
```

Выведет ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f1916709d1071d49d01e0a0d2c2c598a)):

> collection has 3 elements
> collection has 9 elements, element of collection (7) is "val 7"

Comment: Спасибо!
Подскажите еще тогда пожалуйста, я хочу вывести определённый элемент коллекции, использую следующий запрос:
`DECLARE author_jobes varchar_tbl;
ajb1 varchar_tbl;
J integer:= 0;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(author_jobes.LAST);
END;`
Но developer ругается, что указанный мной набор не инициализирован, что я упускаю в данном конструкторе?

Comment: _что я упускаю в данном конструкторе?_, всё упустили, вы его просто  не вызвали.

Comment: Дополнил вам пример вызовом конструктора.

Comment: Спасибо, со всем разобралась!

Comment: @Лидия Рад был помочь!